# Is it possible to use abbreviations with cleveref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to use the full name in most circumstances for references. But sometimes, e.g. in

```
$\xRightarrow{\cref{prop:15.2d}}$
```

the full name might be too long. In this example, it gives "Proposition 11.15 (d)"

So I would like to use something like

```
$\xRightarrow{\crefabbr{prop:15.2d}}$
```

to get something like "11.15 (d)" or "Prop. 11.15 (d)"

Does `cleveref` have a feature like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can use `\crefname`, `\Crefname` inside a group lo locally redefine the string used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

\crefname{prop}{\text{Proposition}}{\text{Propositions}}
\Crefname{prop}{\text{Proposition}}{\text{Propositions}}

% Commands for local abbreviations
\newcommand\crefabbr[1]{%
\begingroup
  \crefname{prop}{\text{Prop.}}{\text{Props.}}\cref{#1}
\endgroup%
}
\newcommand\Crefabbr[1]{%
\begingroup
  \Crefname{prop}{Prop.}{Props.}\Cref{#1}
\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}

$\xRightarrow{\ref{prop:15.2d}}$

$\xRightarrow{\crefabbr{prop:15.2d}}$

$\xRightarrow{\cref{prop:15.2d}}$

\begin{prop}
\label{prop:15.2d}
test
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that if you are only interested in the number, it's enough to use the standard `\ref`.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. No, I am not only interested in the number, but also in an abbreviation in front of the number, because I think it makes it easier for the reader to find the referenced entity.